# How can you get a list or traversable tree of bookmarks from within a Firefox Extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, oop, firefox-addon, bookmarks

I am working on a simple Firefox Extension, and I need a list of the user's bookmarks. I have found the [nsINavBookmarksService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsINavBookmarksService#getChildFolder.28.29) class which appears to be the recommended way of manipulating bookmarks since Firefox 3.0. Strangely I don't see a method that I could use to get a list of all the bookmarks in a folder. I need some way of creating a flat list of all the Bookmark URIs, but without any methods that return information about more than one bookmark I don't see a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial is what you want [Places Query API](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Retrieving_part_of_the_bookmarks_tree)

The bookmarks are in a sqlite file in the profile directory and you need to use the query api to read them.

Good luck!